# how to do some calculation when find record in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection like this:

```
{
    "male_count": 500,
    "female_count": 501
}
```

now I want to find `male_ratio`(`male_ratio = male_count /(male_count + female_count)`), something like:

```
select (male_count / (male_count + female_count)) as male_ratio from collection_name
```

how can I do this in shell?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) with a [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "male_ratio": {
           "$divide": [
               "$male_count",
               { "$add": [ "$male_count", "$female_count" ] }
           ]
       }
    }}
])
```

The `.aggregate()` method has both access to the [operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-arithmetic/) to do the calculations as well as the ability to "alter" document contents. The `.find()` method can really only "select" fields and "filter" results.